# How to use pattern matching in this if/else?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I wrote an function with an if/else-clause, but thought about possibilities to use pattern matching. I failed, but would appreciate seeing how it could have been done for the learning outcome of it.

```
def sha1():String = {
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("OS X")){
       ("x.tif" !!).toString
    }
    else{
      "failed"
    }
}
```

I tried this with the logic that i hoped that the string would take part in the test ("test" contains("0S X") is legal). This causes an error.

```
 def sha2(command:String):String = System.getProperty("os.name") match {
    case contains("OS X")=> ("x.tif" !!).toString

}
```

The second attempt would be to write something like, where I match on the input to a function call:

```
def sha3():String = System.getProperty("os.name").contains(x) match {
    case x=="OS X" => "hello"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be an option to express by using pattern match

```
def sha1():String = System.getProperty("os.name") match {
  case s if s.contains("OS X") => ("x.tif" !!).toString
  case _ => "failed"
}
```

If your code really has just one `case` then approach using `if` `else`could be nicer though

```
def sha1(): String = 
  if ( System.getProperty("os.name").contains("OS X") )
    ("x.tif" !!).toString
  else
    "failed"
```

Comment: thanks, I assumed it was simple. I think I will extend it with more tests and then I think pattern matching grows nicer syntactically. Why you reposted my if/else function?

Comment: I reposted a syntactically changed version dropping the superfluous parentheses. Sometimes this reads nicer. If you could move the if check to a short function you would end up with a nice one liner. `if ( isOSX )  ("x.tif" !!).toString else "failed"`

Comment: ok. I am not a fan of dropping the parenthesis if Scala treats it the same way C does (one line is connected to the if, add another line and that is not connected to the if, and thus is executed independent of the if test result).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need pattern matching for this. Just do:

```
"OS X".r
  .findFirstIn(System.getProperty("os.name"))
  .map { _ => ("x.tif" !!).toString }
  .getOrElse("failed")
```

Comment: I would like to add additional cases (linux and windows), and I dont think that your method here scales well in that regards.